# MySql Database Connection Issues - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I am attempting to fetch User Information, and then display it onto a Table in Swing. Currently I am getting an error as follows each time I execute the piece of code below.

### Error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at me.sage.hopkins.gui.and.mysql.Test.initialize(Test.java:53)
at me.sage.hopkins.gui.and.mysql.Test.<init>(Test.java:41)
at me.sage.hopkins.gui.and.mysql.Test$1.run(Test.java:28)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

### Code

```
public class Test {

private JFrame frame;
private JTable table;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Test window = new Test();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Test() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //*Mysql Configurations*\\
    Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://204.44.86.142/League_Stats","root","password");
    PreparedStatement sql = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `Champion Data`");
    ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    String ChampionName = rs.getString("Champion");
    String UserName = rs.getString("User Name");

    String[] columnNames = {"Username", "Champion"};
    Object[]data = {UserName, ChampionName};
    //*Draw Table*\\
    table = new JTable((Object[][]) data, columnNames);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_table = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_table.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_table.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_table.gridx = 2;
    gbc_table.gridy = 6;
    frame.getContentPane().add(table, gbc_table);


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**New Error**

This is the new error I recieved after introducing the JDBC Library.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;
at me.sage.hopkins.gui.and.mysql.Test.initialize(Test.java:65)
at me.sage.hopkins.gui.and.mysql.Test.<init>(Test.java:41)
at me.sage.hopkins.gui.and.mysql.Test$1.run(Test.java:28)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The JDBC driver is not within the programs class path

Comment: *"How do I fix that?"*  These are the types of things you should have figured out before attempting to write a GUI.

Comment: The depends entirely on how you are building the program and how you are running it. If you are using an IDE, you need to make sure the JDBC driver .jar file is included within the projects library classpath.  You should also ensure that the IDE is building and including the project dependencies.

Comment: I am using Eclipse to compile this.

Answer (score 1):

Download the jdbc driver. For that you can use this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Then in eclipse

1. Right click your project
2. click on properties
3. Select java build path
4. Select libraries
5. press add external jars
6. select the jar file you have downloaded
7. click ok

This might fix your problem.

Comment: I added the external Jar and now I am getting a different error. Which is under "New Error"

Comment: I added it to the full post. Under "New Error" at the bottom of the post.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;