# MySql - Java - Class Not Found Exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to use JDBC to access the MySql database on my computer. I get this error message

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
at FunctionClass.special_function(FunctionClass.java:72)
at FunctionClass.<init>(FunctionClass.java:25)
at EvaluateFunctions.main(EvaluateFunctions.java:12)
```

I've seen on the other posts that this is due to the fact that the driver is not in the lib directory of the JDK. I tried that and it still doesn't work. I added the *.jar file to my "/usr/lib/default-java/lib/" folder on Xubuntu. I am not using any kind of servers. Here is my code that connects to the database:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Does anyone know what I am missing here?
Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Have you added the driver in your build path

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085364/mysql-database-connection-issues-classnotfoundexception/27085441#27085441

Comment: @johny Thanks. Now it works when I do it on eclipse. However, do you know a link where I can do this through the command line? I tried some and they just didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using eclipse or some ide you can add the jar files to your `build path`.

It can be done by checking this link for eclipse. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27085441/4083590

If you are using command prompt you should add the jar files to your `CLASSPATH`. It can be done as shown below.

- **Linux**:

  `CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH;{Current working directory};{Direct Path to .jar file}`

  `CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH;/home/users/xyz/workspace/;/home/users/xyz/workspace/xyz.jar`

  **Note**: `./` can be used to signify current working directory
- **Windows**:

  `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%:{Current working directory}:{Direct path to .jar file}`

  `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%:C:\users\xyz\workspace:C:\users\xyz\workspace\xyz.jar`

After doing this you would be able to compile your program.